# Multi Column Bar chart in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I'm learning Pandas and need some help in improving the aesthetics of my plot.

**Problem** I'm trying to plot a multi-column bar chart in pandas (either using Matplotlib or through Seaborn library). Two main columns in my data are

**Pages** - main column giving where the user has landed

**action** - once the user lands on this what action does he take. Count of action taken is given in **action_view** column.

So, Pages column should be outer covering inside which there should be 'action' column values. Here's the data below.

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'pages':('home','home','home','food','food','food','electronics','electronics','electronics','payment','payment','payment'),
    'action':('view ','added','checkout','cart viewed','added','bundled','added','product list viewed','checkout','checkout','view','removed'),
    'page_view':(100,100,100,40,40,40,70,70,70,500,500,500),
    'action_view':(30000,10000,5000,300,500,800,1500,1200,1800,1200,1400,1500)          
})

#Code for plot
sns.barplot(x='pages',y='action_view',hue='action',data=sample_df)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel('pages')
plt.ylabel('action_view')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))

#Below is the image that I'm getting
```

[image]

**Question**

1. In the original data, I have 10 different pages and 10 different set of actions so following this approach the bar plot looks very messy. How can I better visualize this?
2. How can I increase the width (thickness) of each individual bars? Also, is there any way to border individual bars (showing distinction b/w each boundary of action bars)?
3. How can I enclose legend in a box?
4. Using *seaborn* package I was able to generate this plot but it
   couldn't work through using *matplotlib*.
5. Also, one page like *home* has a very high *action* count which skews the bar chart. Any thoughts on what can be done to have better visibility on other *pages* action.
6. Lastly, if I want to sort my bars using _**page_view**_ column will I use *sortvalue* function?

Greatly appreciate your help and suggestions in this. Clearing these doubts will help in future learning. 
FYI - I'm using Ipython notebook and Python 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

3) plt.legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))